# How to suppress htmlunit (Java library) warning/error messages?

Tags: java, logging, htmlunit, java.util.logging

I'm using htmlunit [http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/] and it spews out a bunch of warnings/error:

> Mar 24, 2017 6:37:30 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
>   INFO: Bad input type: "datetime", creating a text input
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:32 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:34 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:34 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: :x).] sourceName=[https://www.example.com/bundles/jquery?v=u8J3xxyrazUhSJl-OWRJ6I82HpC6Fs7PQ0-l8XzoZXY1] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:35 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:35 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:35 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Mar 24, 2017 6:37:43 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.dom.Document createElement
>   INFO: createElement: Provided string 'iframe name="rufous-frame-29_-1">https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js] line=[9] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]

I've looked at other resources and tried to turn it off by:

```
    Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

and:

```
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.EDGE);
```

but it **does not work**.

What else can be done to suppress these warning/error messages?

Comment: Ensure you are setting the logger before calling HtmlUnit. If not, please post your complete code

Comment: Thanks, I put the code and one more line (see my answer) and the errors/sarnings stopped appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not going set the loggers to `OFF` in 'logging.properties' file then you need [pin the loggers with a hard reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689831/log-file-not-being-updated-after-few-seconds-while-using-logger-and-filehandler/22698423#22698423) before you set the level to OFF.

Here is a corrected example based off your code:

```
private static final Logger[] PINNED_LOGGERS;
static {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
    PINNED_LOGGERS = new Logger[]{
        Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit"),
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http")
    };

    for (Logger l : PINNED_LOGGERS) {
        l.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I put the following at the start of the application and the errors/warnings stopped:

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: You should [pin those loggers in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689831/log-file-not-being-updated-after-few-seconds-while-using-logger-and-filehandler/22698423#22698423) before you set them to `OFF`.  Otherwise you risk losing those settings you just applied.

Comment: I don't understand that. I don't need to keep those logs.

Comment: If the loggers are not pinned by some code before you set them to `OFF` it is possible for loggers to be garbage collected.  If that happens before htmlunit pins them, it is like you never set them to `OFF`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw them appearing again. It's annoying, like what you said. I don't understand the link you gave me either. What is the simplest way to keep those logs out?