# Java file logger being hijacked and redirected into a file belonging to another logger (from Gigaspaces API) after creation

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging, gigaspaces

I'm seeing a rather odd issue.

I created some standard Java loggers (using Logger.getLogger(), a FileHandle, and a SimpleFormatter.)
Those work fine, and output the log file as expected.

Then, I used some classes from the Gigaspaces API (com.gigaspaces.gs-openspaces - included via a Maven dependency), which includes its own logging.
After that, all of the output of my loggers ended up inside the Gigaspaces log file (e.g. ~/.m2/repository/com/gigaspaces/logs/2017-03-27~12.46-gigaspaces-service-135.60.146.142-23534.log) instead of in the appropriate log files that they are supposed to be using.

If I then create more loggers after I've initialised Gigaspaces, these new loggers work as expected.  Only loggers created before initialising gigaspaces are affected.

I tried poking around in the code for Gigaspaces a little bit, there's a lot of code in there.  I didn't see anything immediately obvious.

Am I doing something wrong with setting up my loggers?  It doesn't seem right that a library can steal the output from pre-existing loggers that are unrelated to its classes.

The below short test program demonstrates the problem:

```
    Logger testLog = Logger.getLogger("testlog");
    try {
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("testlog.log");
        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        testLog.addHandler(fh);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Not important
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    testLog.log(Level.INFO, "This appears in the main log file");

    // Spin up gigaspaces, even by trying to connect to a space that doesn't exist
    UrlSpaceConfigurer testSpaceConfigurer = new UrlSpaceConfigurer("jini://*/*/testSpace?locators=127.0.01").lookupTimeout(1);
    try {
        GigaSpace g = new GigaSpaceConfigurer(testSpaceConfigurer).gigaSpace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // This will throw an exception, just ignore it.
    }
    testSpaceConfigurer.close();

    testLog.log(Level.INFO, "This appears in the (wrong) gigaspaces log file");
```

Comment: I guess GigaSpaces is using another logging framework (log4j, logback, whatever) that by default redirects logging from other services to its framework.

Comment: I checked, and it doesn't seem to have any dependencies on log4j or any other framework.  It does have a transitive dependency on (Avalon) LogKit.  I tried excluding that through Maven, and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the security manager, as suggested by jmehrens, seems to be the way to go.
I was able to stop Gigaspaces from stealing the logging by denying it permission to run the reset() methods on the LogManager, thusly:

```
// Silly hack to keep gigaspaces from STEALING ALL OUR LOGS
static {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkPermission(Permission p) {
            if (p instanceof LoggingPermission) {
                for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : new Exception().getStackTrace()) {
                    if (stackTraceElement.getMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase("reset") && stackTraceElement.getClassName().equalsIgnoreCase("java.util.logging.LogManager")) {
                        throw new SecurityException("No resetting the logger!  It is forbidden.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I this case, I just added the override in a static block of the class that creates my gigaspace instances, but anywhere before initialising them should do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [pin the "testlog" logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689831/log-file-not-being-updated-after-few-seconds-while-using-logger-and-filehandler/22698423#22698423) or you risk losing all of the changes you apply to it.

Modifying loggers requires permissions.  One option might be to use a custom security manager that doesn't let GigaSpaces redirect your logging.

If GigaSpaces is calling [LogManager.reset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#reset--), then one hacky, smelly, dirty way to get around removing your handler is to extend FileHandler and override equals.

```
public class GigaSpaces {

    //Pin the logger
    private static final Logger testLog = Logger.getLogger("testlog");
    static {
        try {
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("testlog.log") {
                public boolean equals(Object o) {
                    return false; //Pure Evil.
                }
            };

            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            testLog.addHandler(fh);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Not important
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void foo() throws Throwable {
        testLog.log(Level.INFO, "This appears in the main log file");

        // Spin up gigaspaces, even by trying to connect to a space that doesn't exist
        UrlSpaceConfigurer testSpaceConfigurer = new UrlSpaceConfigurer("jini://*/*/testSpace?locators=127.0.01").lookupTimeout(1);
        try {
            GigaSpace g = new GigaSpaceConfigurer(testSpaceConfigurer).gigaSpace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // This will throw an exception, just ignore it.
        } finally {
            testSpaceConfigurer.close();
        }

        testLog.log(Level.INFO, "This appears in the (wrong) gigaspaces log file");
    }
}
```